# Oracle SQL Min in Select Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, hsqldb, min

Can some one please help me in writing a sql query that should do a oracle min function based on the following conditions.

For eg for column values

- 0,0,0,0 then output should be 0
- 0,null,0,null then output should be o
- 0,2,4,5,6 then output should be 2 (Note that we are excluding Zero here)
- 0,2,null,4,5 then output should be 2 (same here we are excluding zero)
- null,null,null, null then output should be null.

I wrote query already that satisfies  all the above cases but failing for last case when all the column values are null. Instead of returning null it is returning 0. Can some one modify the below query to fit for the last case as well?

select NVL(MIN(NULLIF(columnname,0)),0) from tablename;

Please also keep in mind that the query should be runnable in oracle as well as hsqldb as we are using hsql db for running junits.

Answer (score 1):

If all 4 cases satisfied by your query then just a case will solve your problem.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(COLUMNNAME) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE NVL(MIN(NULLIF(COLUMNNAME,0)),0) END FROM TABLENAME;
```

Note:- assuming all the cases satisfied by your query except 5th.

Comment: Thanks D.J. This really helped me a lot ! why couldn't I think of CASE..:-)

Answer (score 0):

I will show below an input table with two columns, `ID` and `VAL`, to illustrate the various possibilities. You want a single result per `ID` (or even for the entire table), so this must be a job for `GROUP BY` and some aggregate function. You want to distinguish between three types of values: Greater than zero, zero, and null (in this order); you want to pick the "highest priority group" that exists for each `ID` (in this order of priority), and for that priority group only, you want to pick the min value. This is **exactly** what the aggregate `FIRST/LAST` function does. To order by the three "classes" of values, we use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause of the aggregate `LAST` function.

The `WITH` clause below is not part of the solution - I only include it to create test data (in your real life situation, use your actual table and column names and remove the entire `WITH` clause).

```
with
  inputs ( id, val ) as (
    select 1, 0    from dual union all
    select 1, 0    from dual union all
    select 1, 0    from dual union all
    select 2, 0    from dual union all
    select 2, null from dual union all
    select 2, 0    from dual union all
    select 3, 0    from dual union all
    select 3, 2    from dual union all
    select 3, 5    from dual union all
    select 4, 0    from dual union all
    select 4, 3    from dual union all
    select 4, null from dual union all
    select 5, null from dual union all
    select 5, null from dual
  )
select   id,
         min(val) keep (dense_rank last order by case when val > 0 then 2
                                                      when val = 0 then 1
                                                      else              0 
                                                 end
                       ) as min_val
from     inputs
group by id
order by id
;    

        ID    MIN_VAL
---------- ----------
         1          0
         2          0
         3          2
         4          3
         5
```

Comment: Thanks mathguy for answering but unfortunately I can't do group by or order by in my current code and moreover I'm not sure if hsqldb supports dense rank functions like oracle or may be it is... I don't know. Either the case thanks much for answering my post.